# How can I access a nested discriminated union value?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

I created a nested discriminated union:

```
type hsAlgorithm = HS256 | HS384 | HS512
type rsAlgorithm = RS256 | RS384 | RS512
type esAlgorithm = ES256 | ES384 | ES512

type Algorithm = 
     | HMAC of hsAlgorithm
     | RSA of rsAlgorithm
     | ECDsa of esAlgorithm
```

I create an `Algorithm` variable:

```
> let a = HMAC HS256;;
val a: Algorithm = HMAC HS256
```

Is there a property to directly access `HS256`?

I wrote a function which matches the algorithm and returns the value but I wonder whether I can access the value directly.
Below is my function to match the value:

```
let extractAlgorithm (algorithm: Algorithm) =
      match algorithm with
      | HMAC x -> x.ToString()
      | RSA x -> x.ToString()
      | ECDsa x -> x.ToString()
```

Comment: The problem is that if you only have an `Algorithm` type, the compiler can't know what type the inner value (e.g. `HS256`) will have.  So, the property would be of unknown type.  I'd suggest re-thinking your types.

Comment: I think the question is very unclear. You do access the values of the inner DUs, and convert their names to strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is "no". Each DU case can contain different types so there isn't generally a way to access the value inside each one in a common way. If you find yourself needing this then you could probably find a better type structure. Here's a possible alternative:

```ml
type SHA =
    | SHA256
    | SHA384
    | SHA512
    member this.IdSuffix =
        match this with
        | SHA256 -> "256"
        | SHA384 -> "384"
        | SHA512 -> "512"

type AlgoType = 
     | HMAC
     | RSA
     | ECDsa
     member this.IdPrefix =
        match this with
         | HMAC -> "HS"
         | RSA -> "RS"
         | ECDsa -> "ES"

// Use a record to define an algorithm, because every algorithm has a type AND a "HS"
type Algorithm =
    { AlgoType : AlgoType
      SHA : SHA }
    member this.Id = this.AlgoType.IdPrefix + this.SHA.IdSuffix

let algo = { AlgoType = HMAC; SHA = SHA256 }

algo.Id // returns "HS256"
```

**Side note**: Avoid using `.ToString()` or `string` on DUs. It's actually **very** slow and has caused significant performance issues for me in the past, even when working on relatively simple applications. See [here](https://www.compositional-it.com/news-blog/dont-use-tostring-on-discriminated-unions-in-f/) for more details. I've included members on the types above to build up the algorithm's ID string.

Comment: Fantastic solution! Also, thanks a lot for your link!

Answer (score 1):

> but I wonder whether I can access the value directly.

You can make nested match patterns, like this:

```
let extractAlgorithm (algorithm: Algorithm) =
      match algorithm with
      | HMAC(HS384) -> "HS"
      | RSA x -> x.ToString()
      | ECDsa x -> x.ToString()
```

If you mean: how to access all these `x` as a single `x`, then the answer is: it depends. Only if all `x` have the same type, you can write something like the following (this won't work with your code):

```
let extractAlgorithm (algorithm: Algorithm) =
      match algorithm with
      | HMAC x
      | RSA x
      | ECDsa x -> x.ToString()
```

But since F# is a type-safe language, and you have defined three different types for each of the `HMAC|RSA|ECDSa` types, it won't let you do that.

If all you want is access to `ToString()`, just use the `string` function. You can just do: `string algorithm`. And more in general, you shouldn't use `.ToString()` as it is unsafe and may raise an NRE, where `string` never fails.